# SQL - Each column have one conditional

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one question, I want select from table, but have alias column, with each column have one conditional.

```
Select Value, Target, Plan from Product
```

With Value have condition: `where Product.DetailCode = 'A'` column `Value =Product.Value * 10` , Target have condition: `where Product.DetailCode = 'B'`,
column `Value =Product.Value * 100`

EDIT: I want like in C#:

```
if(Product.DetailCode == 'A') {Value = Product.Value * 10} else if(Product.DetailCode == 'B') {Value = Product.Value * 100}
```

EDIT2: Thanks for all,
Finally, I have own my answer.

> `select
>        case when product.code = 'A' then product.Value * 10  end  as Value,
>        case when product.code = 'B' then product.Value * 100  end  as Target 
>     from product`

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What about `where Product.DetailCode = 'A' and Product.DetailCode = 'A'`? Is that not working?

Comment: looking for something like : `where Product.DetailCode = 'A' or Product.DetailCode = 'A'`

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select   
 case when Product.DetailCode = 'A' then 100
     WHEN  Product.DetailCode = 'B' then 10 end * Product.Value as value 
    , TARGET
    , Plan 
from Product
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
SELECT 
Value =  
      CASE Product.DetailCode  
         WHEN 'A' THEN Product.Value * 10
         WHEN 'B' THEN Product.Value * 100
         ELSE Product.Value * 100 
      END
, Target, Plan
FROM Product
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
After reading your Changes:

```
Select
   if(Product.DetailCode = 'A', value *10, if(Product.DetailCode = 'B', value * 100, value)) AS target
```

This will use value*10 if detailcode is a,  value*100 if detailCode is B and value if detailCode is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a lookup table instead of hard coding conditions like that. The query may look as follows

```
select p.Value * coalesce(l.koeff,1) Value, Target, Plan 
from Product p
left join Lookup l on p.DetailCode = l.Code
```